# Java reflections method to get annotated field as SelenideElement

Tags: java, reflection, cucumber, bdd, selenide

I am using Cucumber with Selenide for my UI tests and I have these methods

```
public static void initPage(String pageName) throws Exception {
    Set<Class<?>> annotated = new Reflections(PAGES_PACKAGE).getTypesAnnotatedWith(PageTitle.class);

    for (Class classToInit : annotated) {
        PageTitle annotation = (PageTitle) classToInit.getAnnotation(PageTitle.class);
        if (annotation.name().equals(pageName)) {
            classToInit.newInstance();
            lastInitialized = substringAfter(classToInit.toString(), "class ");
            lastInitClass = classToInit;
            return;
        }
    }

    throw new AutotestError("Could not find page to init: " + pageName);
}

public static SelenideElement findElementByTitle(String elementName) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Set<Field> annotated = new Reflections(lastInitialized, new FieldAnnotationsScanner()).getFieldsAnnotatedWith(ElementTitle.class);

    for (Field field : annotated) {
        ElementTitle annotation = field.getAnnotation(ElementTitle.class);
        if (annotation.name().equals(elementName)) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            SelenideElement el = (SelenideElement) field
            return el;
        }
    }
    throw new AutotestError("Element not found: " + elementName);
}
```

I am very new to reflections and am trying to build a page objects pattern utilising the org.reflections.Reflections library to search for annotated fields in various page object classes. I am, however, having problems returning the SelenideElement from the field I'm getting in the second method (line SelenideElement el = ... is plain wrong at the moment). How do I get the field I can use as a SelenideElement (with @ElementTitle and @FindBy annotations) in my test? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the problematic line of code like this:

```
SelenideElement el = (SelenideElement) field.get(page(lastInitClass);
```

where page() is com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.page, which is Selenide wrapper for Selenium pageFactory, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should change line
`SelenideElement el = (SelenideElement) field`
to
`SelenideElement el = ((SelenideElement) field.get(pageObject))`

**Explanation**

According to documentation of Field.get:
Returns the value of the field represented by this Field, on the specified object. The value is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a primitive type.

Comment: I've tried using get() method of Field, but it requires Object passed as parameter. I've tried passing the page (class) I called method in, tried passing the page containing this field - all to no avail. It throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideElement field com.suntotem.sbbol.pageobj.MainHeaderPage.loginButton to java.lang.Class

Comment: According to documentation: parameter object from which the represented field's value is to be extracted. 

So you should pass as a parameter a Page where your web element is placed. But not a page class! Only object of you page.